# How to connect to local host of another machine with android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, localhost

I am developing an app for android (with react-native) which is running in android studio emulator. This app should connect to a server, but I am in the testing phase and I run the server in a localhost port. but the localhost of another machine (which is in the same network that I am)

let's say the (local) IP of the other machine is 172.17.240.223 and the port which the server is running on is 8080

when I type 172.17.240.223:8080 in my browser (laptop browser), I get the response and there is no problem. Even when I type this in my browser in the emulator I get the response, but this won't happen in app. why is that?

Comment: Are there any logs in LogCat?

Comment: what is logCat?

Comment: LogCat is a view in AndroidStudio that helps with debugging. For example if your app crashes unexpectedly, you look into LogCat, there you will see the exception stack trace, like: in what class and what line caused the crash. More info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat. In your case, it can be the connection fails because of some particular reason, you should inspect the logs and figure out if there's anything relevant that could suggest you what the problem is. Also have a look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Answer (score 0):

More generally, it's not possible to customize the URL and how the bundle gets loaded. This flexibility is useful to have.
check issue on github [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2704#issue-106469493)

in this case ,you can use testflight for IOS testing and for android just create apk.